# Javascript - Summing variables together

Tags: javascript, xml, rest

Im having issues trying to get variables to add (sum) together to get the total value of the variables. From what ive tried so far;

*Prefacing the variables with a '+' to get their numeric value

*Using parseFloat() and parseInt() to get their numeric value

However i havent had any luck with them

So far all that is returned is

`[object Object][object Object][object Object]`

Below is the snippet of my code

```
    varOpexAmount  = $(xml).find('d\\:OpexAmount ')

    varPreCapexorCapexAmount  = $(xml).find('d\\:PreCapexorCapexAmount ')

    varSuppCapexAmount = $(xml).find('d\\:SuppCapexAmount')

    varBudget = varOpexAmount + varPreCapexorCapexAmount + varSuppCapexAmount;
    $("#Budget").append(varBudget);
```

Comment: do a `console.log()` for all the variables (other than `varBudget`)

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like this:

```
varOpexAmount  = parseFloat($(xml).find('d\\:OpexAmount ').val());

varPreCapexorCapexAmount  = parseFloat($(xml).find('d\\:PreCapexorCapexAmount ').val());

varSuppCapexAmount = parseFloat($(xml).find('d\\:SuppCapexAmount').val());

varBudget = varOpexAmount + varPreCapexorCapexAmount + varSuppCapexAmount;
$("#Budget").append(varBudget);
```

I have used `parseFloat` above, but you may use `parseInt` if and where necessary.

**Also, you may not need to parse the value, if it's already an int or float.**

Basically, you are trying to add jQuery objects. Instead, you need to get the value represented by the object and parse it (using parseFloat or parseInt) where necessary before using it.

Comment: `.val()` is for the value of input fields in the DOM, not XML data.

Answer (score 0):

$() returns a JQuery object.

you have to extract the text from it first.

```
+ $("#whatever").text()
```

or

```
+ $("whatever").val()
```

Comment: `.val()` is just for HTML input fields, not XML.